# Oyoaha look and feel in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

I m using windows 7. I want to use Oyoaha look and feel in Java Swing. I dont know the class name for Oyoaha. Please tell me how to use the LookAndFeel?

Oyoaha.jar can be found in : http://sourceforge.net/projects/oalnf/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either:

```
OyoahaLookAndFeel laf = new OyoahaLookAndFeel();
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(laf);
```

or:

```
...
// get laf class name
System.out.println(laf.getClass().getName());
// prints "com.oyoaha.swing.plaf.oyoaha.OyoahaLookAndFeel"
...
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.oyoaha.swing.plaf.oyoaha.OyoahaLookAndFeel");
```

Comment: Thank u vry much.Is there any Transparent(Skinnable) glassy window themes or mac themes.I m a begineer.where should i place the jar?Give me the class name also.

Comment: @user1446431: you should place the jar anywhere in your casspath (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29); class name is in the answer (see last line); concerning glassy LAF you may also look at http://code.google.com/p/seaglass

Comment: This thing gives me some internal NullPointerException... something about scrollbars... weird...